# react classname is not picking inline style

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, inline

I am using dynamic content in my react app. The content is loading fine. I am trying to change the style of the paragraph tag on the basis of a dynamic value. The style also changes on click event of the paragraph tag. When I click the paragraph the text is changing but the previous selected styles remains in effect and does not change with the dynamic value. Code which is changing the style is

```
if(ans){
        return ans.map((a, index) => {
            return(
                <div className="options-container" key={index}>
                        <p onClick={this.handleOptionClick} className={a.IsChecked ? 'option-selected' : 'option'}>{a.Awnser}</p>
                </div>
            )} 
        );
    }
```

the style for this is

```
.options-container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
}

.option {
    background-color: $blue;
    border-radius: $button-radius;
    color: $white;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: $md auto;
    padding: $normal;
    transition: 0.3s linear all;
    text-align: center;
    width: 90%;
}

.option-selected {
    background-color: $green;
    border-radius: $button-radius;
    color: $white;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: $md auto;
    padding: $normal;
    transition: 0.3s linear all;
    text-align: center;
    width: 90%;
}
```

Comment: Hey. Can you show `handleOptionClick` what is written inside this function? 
Code seems fine. Classname should be picked up based on `Ischecked` value. You can also paste your `ans` object for better answer,

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be with `a.IsChecked`, rest of the code looks correct. Confirm whether its value is updating in the component.

Comment: yes a.isChecked is not being called inside return. Outside in console.log it is giving correct values but inside return it lost its value.

Comment: Strangely if you put className={false ? 'option-selected' : 'option'} even then it is not kicking in.

Answer (score 0):

here what I did. I think you are missing something. please take a look if you find some idea.

```html
  handleOptionClick = () => {
    this.setState({ answer: "here is your new value", IsChecked: true });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p
          onClick={this.handleOptionClick}
          className={this.state.IsChecked ? "option-selected" : "option"}
        >
          {this.state.answer}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
```